# Problema de Josephus (recursivo)

Tags: c++, matemática

Esta é a resolução, feita de forma recursiva em C++, do [problema de Josephus](http://marathoncode.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/josephus-problem.html), onde `n` é igual ao numero de pessoas no círculo, e `k` é o numero do passo a ser dado para a próxima pessoa.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(int n, int k){
    if(n==1) return 1;
    return (((f(n-1, k) + k-1)%n)+1);   
}

int main(){
    unsigned int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    cout << f(n, k) << endl;
}
```

Como podem ver o algoritmo funciona, porém eu gostaria de saber como o mesmo funciona, eu não entendi como ele chega no resultado final.

Meu problema é com `f(n, k) = (f(n-1, k) + k-1)%n + 1)`, gostaria de saber como pode isto retornar o valor correspondente à última pessoa a ficar viva no círculo. Gostaria de saber também o que cada valor de retorno de `f(n-1, k)` a cada recursão significa, pois para mim o único que faz sentido é o ultimo, que é o resultado final.

Answer (score 1):

O valor de `f(n-1, k)` é a posição da pessoa a ser salva com uma pessoa a menos, isto é, a solução do problema anterior.

[Exemplo no Ideone](http://ideone.com/O7QmPc)

O programa faz os cálculos do problema, começando do problema mais simples até o problema final.

Basicamente, a solução do problema é uma sequência de números ímpares consecutivos, que volta a 1 **sempre** que o número de pessoas no circulo for uma potência de 2.

A sequência de resultados é **[1(1), 1(2), 3(3), 1(4), 3(5), 5(6), 7(7), 1(8), 3(9), 5(10)...]**

Mas essa sequência é somente quando **k = 2**. Para **k > 2** a sequência é diferente.

Comment: Não consegui entender, você esta dizendo que o numero de retorno é a posição da pessoa com relação a quantas a no circulo na recursão atual?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: Acredito que não seja isso, eu fiz manualmente todos os retornos e eles não batem com a pessoa que deveria ser retirada naquela vez, e chega um ponto que até o 5 é retirado nesta logica...

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não rodei o exemplo não vou afirmar que esteja certo ou não, mas vamos falar rapidamente sobre recursão. Acho que esse é o problema de entendimento. 
Quando você faz uma chamada recursiva a função verifica se o resultado pode ser encontrado ou se deve fazer uma nova chamada. Se fizer uma nova chamada o sistema empilha a chamada anterior, é o mesmo que acontece quando a função A chama a função B, A fica esperando o retorno de B para continuar executando. Só que no caso da recursão a chamada é para a mesma função. Quando o valor chega a 1 é retornado e a chamada anterior pode ser calculada e retorna também seu resultado para a anterior. Isso acontece sucessivamente até chegar na chamada inicial que retorna o valor para impressão.